# Combining text in 2 EditText into one file.txt in internal storage

Tags: java, android, writetofile

Im trying to make a card like this.

```
Name:
Message:
To:
```

And i want to save it in 1 file like .txt into my internal storage. This is the example picture.
[image]

I try this code.  `writeTofile(edt_txt + txtme.getText().toString());`  but didnt work only one EditText is working to save in file.
Help me please. Im newbie here.

This is my code below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    requestPermissions(new String[] {WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
}

init();
btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        writeToFile(edt_text + txtme.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

writeToFile(edt_text + txtme.getText().toString(),your another edit tex);
You need to pass two string parameter to your writeToFile() function.
Add your writeToFile code too.